# Android Book similar to Effective Java (Joshua Bloch)

Tags: java, android

Do you know a book similar to Effective Java but the main concentration is the Android Environment?

I mean, there are a lot of programming resources in android, also in java but what I am thinking is a kind of compilation. A good example: Effective Java book is a compilation of java language best practices.

Surely almost all of java programming discipline advised in Effective Java were applicable in Android app development since applications are both in java language. But what I'm looking for is a book that concentrates not only in java language but the Android environment as well. Like for example, what is the best way to manage singletons in Android, when you should use singletons and when not, another one is managing activities, swipe, gesture management - these I think will be different if you are developing app for Android environment compared to; if you are creating a web app or desktop app.

Comment: There are a bunch of professional books that produced by Addison-Wesly-Professionals may fit your need.